# Taskbar not apearing in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, mate, taskbar

I have dell latitude e4300 core 2 due laptop.  I installed Ubuntu mate 16.04 and properly updated it, but for the past week, the taskbar has not been displaying and other options are not appearing. I have updated it, but problem is not solved.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the desktop environment you are using, but this should work in most cases:

```
mv ~/.config ~/.config-old
```

Log out, then log in. Your configuration is reset. If you want to get back to your old configuration, you can move back the old configuration files.

Comment: Thank you! I had problem with Ubuntu Mate on Raspberry Pi 3. After selecting option "show advanced menu" it has experienced some internal error and the taskbar become all white. Rebooting did not help. Your proposal saved the day!